# Reference to a manually numbered equation

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I want my equation's number to be "1'". I have done so through `\tag{1'}`. But now I don't know how to refer it in my document. Is there a method to call it or numbering equations like 1, 1', 1''?

Comment: I would suggest using `\tag{$1^\prime$}` rather than `\tag{1'}` - the `\prime` is a little cleaner.

Comment: @Werner: No, that is still not good. The number 1 should be obtained by a `\ref` to equation 1. I'll update my answer to show the technic.

Comment: @LeoLiu: Oh, so the `\prime` should be added automatically?

Comment: @Werner: I mean the number. There should not be any manual serial numbers in LaTeX. `\prime` is still typed manaully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\label` and `\eqref` (or `\ref`) as usual. I don't think there is any difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 \tag{A}\label{eq:simple}
\end{equation}

Eq.~\eqref{eq:simple} is simple.

\end{document}
```

---

(To make this question more useful)

To make a equation as a variant of another one, you can use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a+b = b+a \label{eq:comm}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1+2 = 2+1 \tag{\ref{eq:comm}$'$}\label{eq:comm:inst}
              % if hyperref is used, replace \ref with \ref*
\end{equation}

Commutative law \eqref{eq:comm} and an instance \eqref{eq:comm:inst}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: when i use them, equations are numbered like 1, 2, 3 and so on. What i need is 1, 1', 1''

when i use \tag, i am unable to refer it back. this is the problem

Comment: Note that you have to use *both* `\tag{<stuff>}` and `\label{<lab>}`, and then you can refer to `<lab>` with either `\eqref{<lab>}` or `(\ref{<lab>})`. Also note the brackets around `\ref{<lab>}` which is automatically inserted when using `\eqref{<lab>}`.

Comment: Well, then I recover the example I've just deleted.

Comment: If the "equation variant" version is to be used with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), I wonder whether using `\tag{\ref*{eq:comm}$'$}` would be better. Otherwise only a portion of the tag will be hyperlinked. It may also be personal preference at this point.

Comment: @Werner: Then we can use `(\ref{eq:comm}$'$)` (maybe `\vareqref{eq:comm}` with a user-defined macro) instead of `\eqref{eq:comm:inst}`. We needn't change the labels.

Comment: This seems extra work (adding a `\label` in addition to the `\tag`) for no clear gain. One could just use `(A)` or something, if one cares only about the printed appearance.